# How to get last day of specified month in powershell

Tags: powershell, date

I need to get the last day of a month previous from specified.
I have a string (file name), which contains a date in its end. I need to capture the date (already done) and get the last date of the preceding month. For example the string is "proemail vytvoreni_9.2017 2017-10-16", so I need to get 30th September 2017. This is what I have now:

```
$Report = Read-Host "File name"
$Date = [datetime]$Report.Substring($Report.get_Length()-10)
$Last_month = $Date.AddMonths(-1)
$Date_text = $Last_month.ToString().Substring(3,7)
$month_year = ($Date_text.Split("."))
$days_count = [datetime]::DaysInMonth($month_year[1],$month_year[0])
$days_count = $days_count.ToString()
$month = $month_year[0]
$year = $month_year[1]
$Date_limit = [DateTime]($month,$days_count,$year)
```

All works well, except for the last row, that returns this error: Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.DateTime". I tried to convert $month and $year to string by .ToString() method, but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$filename = "proemail vytvoreni_9.2017 2017-10-16"

# Take the date from the filename
$sub = $filename.Substring($filename.Length-10)

# make it into a date format
$filedate = Get-Date -Date $sub

# take that date 2017-10-16 and substracts its own days so in this case substract 16 days, then show me the date
(($filedate).AddDays(-$filedate.Day)).Date
```

Output:

Saturday 30 september 2017 0:00:00

Answer (score 2):

```
(Get-Date).AddDays(-$(Get-Date).Day)

Saturday, September 30, 2017 2:36:19 PM


((Get-Date).AddDays(-$(Get-Date).Day)).Day

30
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at this problem and different solution for this for awhile and here is my answer.

Create any date you want. Here is an easy way to get the month you want.

$date = [datetime]::Parse("11/2019")

Then simply add the next month and remove one day. p

$date.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)

Hope this helps somebody else.